# Por que usar WHERE 1 = 1 numa query SQL?

Tags: sql, procedure

Durante a manutenção de um sistema legado encontrei a seguinte **procedure**:

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @param as varchar(50);

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1';

IF(@param IS NOT NULL)
    SET @sql = (@sql + ' AND Nome = ''' + @param + '''');
EXEC(@sql)
```

A primeira coisa que me chamou atenção foi a condição **where 1 = 1**

- Por que o programador que escreveu essa procedure usou essa condição?

Comment: Relacionado: http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#AND_0.3D0

Comment: Em algumas condições eu uso confesso.

Comment: Tomar cuidado com essa técnica pois quando a utiliza.. se nao vir nada nos outros `ands` o banco vai buscar todos os registros existente na tabela.
Ou seja se tiver 10milhoes de registro e nao tiver outros filtros vai buscar tudo..

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Esta condição em princípio não aparenta ter razão de ser, pois removê-la dá no mesmo.

No entanto, quando as condições do where são geradas dinamicamente, e o programador vai acrescentando-as com `AND` dentro de `if`s, por estas dependerem de outros fatores do programa que gera o SQL, fica clara sua intenção:

Se nao houver condição adicional, a query permanece assim ...

```
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1
```

... mas no caso, se for verdadeira a condição logo em seguida do seu exemplo, ela pode ficar:

```
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1 AND Nome = "Roberto"
```

Note que se não houvesse o `WHERE 1=1`, ela ficaria desta forma, e não funcionaria:

```
SELECT * FROM Destinatario AND Nome = "Roberto" 
  -- temos um erro aqui --^
```

Para uma condição `AND` só, o autor poderia ter posto o `WHERE` dentro da condição, mas se forem varias condiçoes, o `WHERE 1=1` permitiria várias condições separadas, montadas por `if`s diferentes:

```
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1 AND Nome = "Roberto"
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1 AND Cidade = "Santos"
SELECT * FROM Destinatario where 1 = 1 AND Nome = "Roberto" AND Cidade = "Santos"
```

Assim, o `AND Nome` poderia estar em um `if` e o  `AND Cidade` em outro, e todos funcionariam independente de ter que saber se já há um `if` anterior no código que gera o *SQL*.

Como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto, o CakePHP, por exemplo, utiliza esta técnica.

Particularmente, acho melhor usar maneiras mais limpas do que como foi usado, como concatenar com `AND` somente quando se tratar da 2ª condição em diante, mas cada um tem seus critérios, e em cada momento uma determinada técnica pode ser melhor do que outra.

Saindo desse exemplo específico de uso, pode até acontecer de alguém usar um `WHERE` "neutro" quando quer testar alguma condição durante o desenvolvimento do código, eliminando a condição original (equivalente a colocar `WHERE true`, que também serviria para a explicação inicial), mas isto já é outra história.

No nosso caso em específico, o `IF` desta linha confirma a hipótese inicial do parâmetro opcional com `AND`:

```
IF(@param IS NOT NULL) -- <== Aqui 
    SET @sql = (@sql + ' AND Nome = ''' + @param + '''');
```

Comment: Esse tipo de *coringa* era muito usado antigamente? Você pode me mostrar uma alternativa pra essa técnica?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade só vi isso agora, pra responder sua pergunta, eu não faria desta forma. Geralmente eu deixo sem o Where mesmo. Quando são vários where num loop, eu simplesmente começo com um where="WHERE ", e no loop vou pondo where = where + glue + conditio por exemplo. o Glue começa vazio, mas ele vira "AND" dentro da primeira volta do loop, ou seja, só vai ser aplicado do 2o em diante.

Comment: @Laerte O CakePHP usa esse 1=1 para facilitar a geração de queries. Mas como bem disse o Bacco, seria possível evitar.

Comment: Genial! Eu estava com essa dúvida, porque é bem comum no MySQL usar `WHERE 1`, sem o igual.

Comment: Criar uma string a partir de itens numa lista com um separador fixo é um problema bem antigo e quase todas as linguagens dispõem de uma função para resolvê-lo (geralmente chamada de `join`). O ideal é usar isso em vez de reinventar a roda.

Comment: @Gabriel O Join seve bem para fazer a lista... Mas não serve para resolver o que está na pergunta, que é a palavra where. O problema aqui não é o separador, e sim o fato de que se não tiver nenhuma condição, não sobrar um WHERE vazio.

Comment: @Bacco Eu sei. O que eu falei não foi uma tentativa de responder a pergunta, tanto é que não postei como resposta, e sim como comentário. Foi mais um aviso aos navegantes que insistem em escrever um loop na mão fazendo malabarismos com índices numéricos pra recriar a implementação de um `join`.

Comment: @Gabriel ok... só comentei pq como ficou meio "perdido" nos comments sem uma introdução (do tipo: "complementando, criar uma ..." ) achei que talvez você tivesse atentado ao detalhe errado e por bem resolvi estender o assunto.

Comment: @Bacco A minha maior motivação foi o trecho: "_acho melhor usar maneiras mais limpas do que como foi usado, como concatenar com AND somente quando se tratar da 2ª condição em diante_" que provavelmente vai incentivar as pessoas a fazer o velho loop que eu citei antes.

Comment: Você sabe que o Join é um loop né? O fato de estar numa função nativa e ter sido escrito pelo autor da linguagem e não pelo da aplicação, não muda esse fato. E tem situações que você quer AND, OR e mais de um tipo de ligação, coisa que o join não resolve. Agora, que em linguagens que tem concatenação múltipla com separador (join no PHP, concat_ws no MySQL, realmente simplifica a digitação do código).

Answer (score 9):

Existem outros pontos interessantes a serem levantados para esta solução com `WHERE 1 = 1`.

## Clareza de código

Uma vantagem desta técnica é que o código acaba ficando **mais limpo**, pois assim não precisa existir o controle da presença do `WHERE` vs `AND/OR`, mantendo independente a ordem dos filtros que vão entrar na consulta e se algum filtro vai entrar na consulta.

## Impacto na performance

Existe uma dúvida recorrente com relação ao impacto de **performance** no banco de dados da presença do `WHERE 1 = 1`, independente se há outros filtros ou não. O que posso dizer que a [maioria dos bancos de dados](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/does-where-1-1-usually-have-an-impact-on-query-performance) não sofre qualquer impacto de performance ao utilizar esta técnica.

Fazendo uma análise de impacto na plano de execução do Sql Server, com 10.000 registros em uma tabela, não notou-se qualquer mudança entre o plano contendo `WHERE 1 = 1` e do plano sem o mesmo.

## Outra opção

Alguns [bancos de dados](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/does-where-1-1-usually-have-an-impact-on-query-performance) suportam também `WHERE 1`, embora esta não seja a opção recomendada por não fazer parte do padrão ANSI.

Comment: Qual o motivo do voto negativo? Tentei acrescentar mais algumas informações além da resposta aceita: código mais limpo, ser opcional quando existe um filtro obrigatório e responde a um questionamento comum de performance. O bounty foi gerado para que uma nova resposta atenda outras preocupações e entendo que foi o que eu fiz.

Comment: Não vou negativar porque a resposta não está errada, e não vejo motivo pra negativarem, claro que acho importante acrescentar informações novas ou relevantes a uma resposta antiga, quando necessário, mas nesse caso não vi nada que acrescentou... Se fosse eu, invés de criar uma nova resposta, editaria a do bacco e acrescentaria essas informações aonde cabem

Comment: Interessante seria quem negativou explicar o motivo do negativo, assim mostrando o seu ponto de vista