# Usar 1=1 no WHERE é errado?

Tags: sql

Esta tendo uma certa disputa para saber se é justificável ou não o uso do *1=1* no `where` de uma query em minha equipe.
Ao usar esse método para gerar querys dinâmicamente traz algum prejuízo em desempenho da query ou isso não influencia?

Comment: [Por que usar WHERE 1 = 1 numa query SQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12525/91)

Comment: Talvez já tenha sido respondido na pergunta linkada pelo rray. Mas você poderia editar a pergunta e colocar mais contexto, exemplo real de uso para vermos se a pergunta não é duplicata da outra.

Comment: Se usar um `join` para formar as condições com um vetor não será necessário `1=1`, pois no `join` um vetor assim `[1, 2, 3]` resultaria nisto: `1 AND 2 AND 3`, claro que isto é um exemplo bem simples.

Comment: @rray 
eu ja tinha lido esse post, e ele não responde a minha pergunta, minha pergunta foi se em desempenho o 1=1 é prejudicial, e sim eu uso o 1=1 para facilitar na hora de por as clausulas na progromação, por isso minha pergunta ñ foi respondida

Comment: @João Não é errado mas é bem feinho :-). Com duas linhas à mais de código o SQL é enviado para o banco apenas com aquilo que realmente importa. Veja o comentário do Bacco na resposta da pergunta linkada. Quanto à performance, o seu banco de dados responde (analise o plano de execução das duas queries - pelo menos na maioria dos bancos será igual).