# Query não funciona dentro do php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Fiz uma query com um join para pegar informações do banco, eu testei no mysql e ela funcionou perfeitamente, o problema é que ela não funciona no php, não da erro na execução porém o retorno é nullo, mesmo se eu troco as variáveis por textos do banco ela  não funciona, utilizei o var_dump() para verificar se havia erro de syntax mas não tem.

```
$query="SELECT t1.* FROM tb_anuncio AS t1 JOIN tb_localizacao AS t2 ON t2.cd_localizacao = t1.cd_localizacao WHERE 1=1 AND t1.cd_categoria =".$categoria->getCd()." AND t2.nm_estado ='".$estado."' AND t2.nm_municipio ='".$municipio."' LIMIT ".$init.",".$max."";

$retorno = $this->conexao->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                     while($anuncio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retorno))
                     {
                         $anuncios[] = $anuncio;

                     }
```

var_dump:

```
"SELECT t1.* FROM tb_anuncio AS t1 JOIN tb_localizacao AS t2 ON t2.cd_localizacao = t1.cd_localizacao WHERE 1=1 AND t1.cd_categoria =1 AND t2.nm_estado ='AC' AND t2.nm_municipio ='Acrelândia' LIMIT 0,17"
```

Mysql
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na $query posso fazer no retorno tbm se quiser, na verdade não é um var_dump eu coloquei um break point no vscode e peguei o conteúdo da variável

Comment: pq `WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: Apenas para ajudar na concatenação

Comment: Se retornou `null`, então o problema é na query.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12525/70

Comment: @Bacco, parabéns, muito bem explicado! Porque não pensei nisso? rs

Answer (score 0):

Tenta forçar a impressão dos erros, talvez teja dando erro só ele não é exibido devido as configurações do servidor, usa isso no inicio do codigo.

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, mesmo mostrando o conteúdo da variável com os valores corretos a query perdia a formatação ao chegar no banco por conta do utf8, utilizei utf8_decode($municipios) é funcionou.

Comment: Apesar de ser um erro de encoding, é bom marcar a sua resposta como aceita pra fechar o assunto pra quem acessar o post em seguida. A pergunta eu já fechei, até pra evitar novas respostas-chute.

Comment: Vou ou marca, só que preciso esperar 11 horas para marcar minha própria resposta como norreta

Comment: Sim, não tem pressa, com o post fechado não tem problema, foi uma sugestão só pra não esquecer mesmo.